# I uploaded a pdf file using sendkeys, deleted that file and again uploaded a different pdf. While doing so, it is taking uploading 1st pdf not 2nd pdf

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys

I uploaded a pdf file using sendkeys, deleted that file and again uploaded different pdf. While doing so, it is taking uploading 1st pdf not 2nd pdf.

Here is my code:

```
public void deWebsitePDFUpload() {
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

    actions.moveToElement(dewebsitePDFUploadAccordian).click().build().perform();
    dewebsitePDFUploadIcon.sendKeys(
        "C:\\Users\\user123\\eclipse-workspace\\test\\sample-files\\Design_Asklepios_20150529-V02.pdf");
    uploadTitle.sendKeys("Uploading German website PDF");
    uploadSaveBtn.click();

    Actions actions1 = new Actions(driver);

    actions1.moveToElement(dewebsitePDFUploadAccordian).click().build().perform();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//a[@class='btn icon'])[2]"))).click();
    System.out.println("delted");

    dewebsitePDFUploadIcon.sendKeys(
        "C:\\Users\\user123\\eclipse-workspace\\test\\sample-files\\Reuters_Branchen_en.pdf");
    uploadTitle.sendKeys("Uploading German 2nd website PDF");
    uploadSaveBtn.click();
}
```

[image]